# DataGridViewLinkColumn formatting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewlinkcolumn

My Application is a windows form application in VB.

I have DataGridView in my Application. The seventh column is defined as DataGridViewLinkColumn when i designed the DataGridView. My Application reads the link from a table and Grid properly displays it.

I don't want my user to see the link, i want them to see a sentence like "Click here to visit" but i couldn't manage to do.

Second, when i click the link nothing happens. I know that i have to handle this in CellContentClick event but i don't know how to call the default browser directed to the link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct property in `DataGridViewLinkColumn` which separates the display text and url.

To achieve your goal, you need to handle two events `CellFormatting` and `CellContentClick`. Subscribe to these events.

In `CellFormatting` event handler, change the formatted value to `Click here to visit`. The flag `FormattingApplied` must be set `True` as this prevents further formatting of the value.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
    If e.ColumnIndex = 'link column index Then
        e.Value = "Click here to visit";
        e.FormattingApplied = True;
    End If
End Sub
```

To open the link in the default browser, use the `Process` class and pass the url as argument to the `Start` method. Put the code in the `CellContentClick` event handler.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.ColumnIndex = 'link column index Then
        Process.Start(dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString());
    End If
End Sub
```